# Tensorflow Tensor object not iterable

Tags: tensorflow, keras

all:
    I am new to tensorflow. I used to use theano as keras backend.
    When I try to use tensorflow instead of theano, I got error saying:
    **'Tensor' object not iterable**
    when call keras.backend.shape() function. Further more, I found this
    error is occurred by tensorflow.shape(). However, when I test         tensorflow.shape
    function with keras.backend.variables() instance, it goes well.
    Can anybody tell me what's going on ?
    keras version: 1.2.1
    tensorflow version: 0.12.1.

Thanks you all guys in advance.